# Can't seem to get welch function in scipy work correctly

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to learn DSP through using Python's scipy package.
I have measure some 200Hz signal from a machine. Now I want to inspect the spectral density of the signal. Here's the signal plotted out:
[image]

As you can see, the signal is obviously not a low frequency signal. However, I still get the PSD graph like below.
Here's the code I have been using:

```
def plot_and_save(sample,i=""):
filepath = sample + "/" + "merged_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set_colodef plot_and_save(sample,i=""):r_codes("dark")
fig1, axes = plt.subplots(3,2)
fig1.figsize = [1920,1080]

axes[0,0].plot(df["Time"], df["Voltage"], marker="",color="blue")
axes[0,0].set_title("Plot of Voltage against time")
axes[0,0].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right", x=1.0)
axes[0,0].set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")

axes[0,1].plot(df["Time"], df["Current"], marker="",color="red")
axes[0,1].set_title("Plot of Current against time")
axes[0,1].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[0,1].set_ylabel("Current (A)")

sampling_freq = 1e6
vol_f, vol_psd = welch(df["Voltage"].to_numpy(), fs=sampling_freq)
axes[1,0].plot(vol_f, vol_psd, marker="",color="green")
axes[1,0].set_title("Plot of Voltage's Power Spectral Density")
axes[1,0].set_xlabel("Frequency", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axfilepath = sample + "/" + "merged_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set_color_codes("dark")
fig1, axes = plt.subplots(3,2)
fig1.figsize = [1920,1080]

axes[0,0].plot(df["Time"], df["Voltage"], marker="",color="blue")
axes[0,0].set_title("Plot of Voltage against time")
axes[0,0].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right", x=1.0)
axes[0,0].set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")

axes[0,1].plot(df["Time"], df["Current"], marker="",color="red")
axes[0,1].set_title("Plot of Current against time")
axes[0,1].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[0,1].set_ylabel("Current (A)")

sampling_freq = 1e6
vol_f, vol_psd = welch(df["Voltage"].to_numpy(), fs=sampling_freq)
axes[1,0].plot(vol_f, vol_psd, marker="",color="green")
axes[1,0].set_title("Plot of Voltage's Power Spectral Density")
axes[1,0].set_xlabel("Frequency", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[1,0].set_ylabel("PSD")

cur_f, cur_psd = welch(df["Current"], fs=sampling_freq)
axes[1,1].plot(cur_f, cur_psd, marker="",color="yellow")
axes[1,1].set_title("Plot of Current's Power Spectral Density")
axes[1,1].set_xlabel("Frequency", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[1,1].set_ylabel("PSD")

axes[2,0].plot(df["Time"], df["Current"]*df["Voltage"], marker="",color="red")def plot_and_save(sample,i=""):
axes[2,0].set_title("Plot of power against time")
axes[2,0].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[2,0].set_ylabel("Watt")

sns.scatterplot(x="Current", y="Voltage", data=df, ax=axes[2,1], color = 'r', edgecolor="None", linewidth=0)
axes[2,1].set_title("Plot of Voltage against Current")
axes[2,1].set_xlabel("Current (A)", ha="right", x=1.0)
axes[2,1].set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")

fig1.suptitle("Sample number: " + str(i+5),fontsize=16)
# plt.savefig("formatted/"+date+"/figure/"+str(i+5)def plot_and_save(sample,i=""):".svg",format="svg")
plt.show()es[1,0].set_ylabel("PSD")

cur_f, cur_psd = welch(df["Current"], fs=sampling_freq)
axes[1,1].plot(cur_f, cur_psd, marker="",color="yellow")
axes[1,1].set_title("Plot of Current's Power Spectral Density")
axes[1,1].set_xlabel("Frequency", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[1,1].set_ylabel("PSD")

axes[2,0].plot(df["Time"], df["Current"]*df["Voltage"], marker="",color="red")
axes[2,0].set_title("Plot of power against time")
axes[2,0].set_xlabel("Time (us)", ha= "right",x=1.0)
axes[2,0].set_ylabel("Watt")

sns.scatterplot(x="Current", y="Voltage", data=df, ax=axes[2,1], color = 'r', edgecolor="None", linewidth=0)
axes[2,1].set_title("Plot of Voltage against Current")
axes[2,1].set_xlabel("Current (A)", ha="right", x=1.0)
axes[2,1].set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")

fig1.suptitle("Sample number: " + str(i+5),fontsize=16)
# plt.savefig("formatted/"+date+"/figure/"+str(i+5)".svg",format="svg")
plt.show()
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Can you approximate the signal frequency by computing peak-to-peak times for a few of the cycles? How does that compare to the dominant frequency of the PSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimum working example for computing a PSD. I think your problem might be that you leave nperseg option to default, which is 256 points, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html). What you want to do is include enough samples in each segments to make sure that the dominant features of the signal are included. My rough guidance would be at least 1.5-2.0 times the period.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import welch

# Generate signal
freq = 1.0 # Hz
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(2.*np.pi*freq*t) + 0.2*np.random.random(len(t))

# Compute no. samples per segment
nSegments = 3
overlap = 0.5

nPerSeg = np.round(len(y)//nSegments / overlap)
if nSegments == 1:
    nPerSeg = len(y)
nOverlap = np.round(overlap * nPerSeg)

# Compute sampling rate.
dt = t[1] - t[0]

# Compute PSD
f, psd = welch(y, fs=1./dt,
    window="hamm", nperseg=nPerSeg, noverlap=nOverlap, nfft=None, detrend="constant",
    return_onesided=True, scaling="density")

# Plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(f/freq, psd)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("f/freq")
plt.ylabel("PSD of y")

plt.show()
```

Expected result shows peak at the main signal frequency:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I revised my code and realised the result was correct the whole time. The reason is that not plotting on a log scale, I thought the frequency with the most power density is at 0Hz (it should be 200Hz). And I only saw that because of your code!